# Codeigniter: Passing databa from helper from two database tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

So basically I have a helper -

```
function records()
{        
  $ci = get_instance();                     
  $ci->db->order_by("date", "desc");
  $ci->db->limit(20);
  $query = $ci->db->get('records');
  $data =array();
  foreach($query->result_array() as $orders)
  {
     $data[] = $orders;
  }            
  return $data;
}
```

I need to pass data from it to view, but currently I'm only passing data from table records. In additional, after I get $data[] from records, I need to check the current record id, and then pass in the same $data[] all user details from another table which is users instead. How can I do it? So basically I muts first get all data from records, check from what user the record is, and then search that user with get_where('users', array('id' => $data['user_id'])); and add user data to either new array or the same $data[] array. Is this something doable? If yes, please show me example of it.

Comment: First of all always create models for database connetions. Helpers is not for using database queries. Use MVC structure with CI to build your application easly. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: can I load models in helpers?

Comment: ok, anyway about my first question, can you help me with it?

Comment: i already helped. Your structure is wrong . re build it and than other problem will be easy

Comment: I'm not entirely clear I understand your question. It would be really very helpful for you to explain what you want to do, rather than trying to explain how you might do it. Also, I agree with @safarov. I'm afraid you need to go back to basics before anyone will be able to help you. You should not use helpers for database queries or for sending data to a view. Please read the MVC description in the user guide. Once you understand the relationship between Controllers, Models and Views then I'm sure your query will be easy for you to work out yourself.

Comment: Also, don't expect people to write the code for you. Many people will help point you in the right direction but simply asking for examples is probably not the way to get good answers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do a join?

```
  $ci->db->order_by("date", "desc");
  $ci->db->limit(20);
  $query = $ci->db->from('records')->join('users', 'records.user_id=users.id')->get();
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Make sure you modify the query to use the correct field name in the records table that references the user's id.  The above comments are right though - helpers are absolutely not the place for queries.  Really, I can't think of any good example of using get_instance to grab the CI object in a helper, they should probably be CI independent functions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly; it is always recommended that you use models for database operations. For retrieving database information from models, it is also recommended that you use libraries. Helpers can be used for the purposes that you do not always need databases, like date calculations, search functions etc.

Secondly; If I understand you right, You are taking records from a table into an array, and then you want to to check if a user has records in that array(or something like this), which the user details come from another database? If yes, then simply you can get all records into an array, get user details (e.g. user id) into another array or variable. The remaining part is all there array operations.